# Expandable AppBar (onPressed)

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

How do I achieve this effect? I wanted to expand my AppBar after clicking on the dates.

[image: Collapsed AppBar]

[image: Expanded AppBar]

Comment: You can use `SliverAppBar` to achieve this.

Comment: Does `SliverAppBar` allow you to disable the scroll? Because I do not want to expand/collapse the `AppBar` with scrolling.

Comment: In this case use the bottom property of AppBar. When it is closed you replace the widget with empty container then when it is open place your widget there

Comment: @ConstantinN. you can open/close the "bottom" property as you wish?

Comment: Ofcourse. See my answer below

Comment: @AyanDas SliverAppBar does not allow you to expand/collapse itself on button click. It reacts to scroll only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to bring toggle a veriable then change the height of the `bottom` widget.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.place),onPressed: (){
          setState((){
            isOpen = !isOpen;
          });
        })],
        bottom: PreferredSize(child: isOpen? Container(color:Colors.red, height: 100):Container(),preferredSize:Size.fromHeight(isOpen? 100:0) ,)
      ),)
```

Comment: Ok, at first sight it seems like this will work. Just one last question: can you animate those changes? For example the opening/closing of the "bottom" property. (I am new to Flutter, please bear with me :D)

Comment: Yes you can. But it is a bit complicated if you're not familiar with `Animations`. If you're familiar with it you only have to `100*animation.value` for the height

Comment: I was still testing if this will do, there you go :)

Comment: @ConstantinN. This works good But I want to change the action's Icon respectively when  isOpen =true? How to achieve this ?

Comment: IconButton(icon: isOpen?Icons.pause:Icons.play)